# I am looking for a partial sting in each row of my pandas Dataframe, I created a Dataframe where the rows are not all equal, so I cannot select by col

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I read in a file and created a Dataframe from that file, the problem is that not all of the information that I read was separated properly and was not the same length. I have a df that has 1600 columns but I do not need them all I specifically need the information that is 3 columns to the left of a specific particular sting in one of the previous columns. For Example:

In the 1st row column number 1000, it has a value of ['HFOBR'] and then I need the column value that is 3 to the left.

In the 2nd row the column number with ['PQOBR'] might be 799 but I still need the value that is 3 to the left.

In the 3rd row the column number might be 400 with ['BBSOBR'] but I still need the lave 3 to the left.

And so on I really am trying to search each row for the partial sting OBR and then take the value of 3 to the left of it and put that value in a new df with a column of its own.

Here you will find a snapshot of the dataframe

[image: This is the picture of my data frame a bit of my code]

Here you will see the code I used to create the dataframe in the first place where I read in an HL7 file and tried to convert it to a Dataframe, and each of the HL7 messages are not the same length whish is casing part of the problem I am having

```
message = []

parsed_msg = []

with open(filename) as msgs:

    start = False

    for line in msgs.readlines():

        if line[:3] == 'MSH':

            if start:

                parsed_msg = hl7.parse_batch(msg)

                #print(parsed_msg)

                start = False

            message += parsed_msg

            msg = line

            start = True

        else:

            msg += line

 

df = pd.DataFrame(message)
```

Comment: Without showing us your code or dataframe, nobody can help you with this question. Please share what you have done so far and what your code looks like.

Comment: Should I post a screenshot? Last time I tried my post was deleted.

Comment: Not necessary. You can post your comments and a snapshot of your dataframe inside code brackets. You can find code sample while editing your post. Try to share your code and even if it is not correct editorially, moderators will correct it.

Comment: I hope this is more what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["HFOBR", "foo", "a", "b", "c"], ["foo", "PQOBR", "a", "b", "c"]])
df
       0      1  2  3  4
0  HFOBR    foo  a  b  c
1    foo  PQOBR  a  b  c
```

Define a function to find the value three columns to the left of the first column containing a string with "OBR"

```
import numpy as np

def find_left_value(row):
    obr_col_idx = np.where(row.str.contains("OBR"))[0]
    left_col_idx = obr_col_idx + 3
    return row[left_col_idx].iloc[0]
```

Apply this function to your dataframe:

```
df['result'] = df.apply(find_left_value, axis=1)
```

Resulting dataframe:

```
       0      1  2  3  4 result
0  HFOBR    foo  a  b  c      b
1    foo  PQOBR  a  b  c      c
```

FYI: making sample data like this that people can test answers on will help you 1) define your problem more clearly, and 2) get answers.

Comment: Thank you for this information but for some reason, it does not work it throws an error '[None of [Int64Index([3], dtype ='int64)] are in [index]' Any Idea why this might be?

Comment: The code as I wrote it runs without error. If you're getting this error when you apply it to your data, then either 1) you changed the code, or 2) there are differences between the toy dataset I made and your real dataset (most likely a difference in column names but I can't be sure). If you want help, you'll have to provide data we can use to replicate the error in a format we can use (ie provide code that will generate that data locally on my computer, NOT a screenshot).